# Remap audio output to other ports?

Tags: windows, audio

I have an Asus M4A785T-M Motherboard which has 5x 3.5mm audio ports and one optical audio port onboard. On Windows 7 x64, is it possible to control which channels output to which ports? For example, my CTR/SUB port currently outputs Center to the left channel and Subwoofer to the Right. Can I reverse these, or better yet, change which ports hold what entirely? The audio driver supplied with my motherboard uses the VIA HD Audio Deck for configuration.

Also, while I'd like a Windows solution, I'm interested in a Linux one just for the sake of learning how, if anyone's up to the task. The system in question doesn't run Linux, though.